# Can't Sum up ruby integers

Tags: ruby, math, integer

I'm getting this error when trying to SUM up each `boxes.percent` into local variable `percent`.

Here is error:

> no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array

My code:

```
<% percent = 0, shares = 0 %>
<% @modification.boxes.each do |d|
  percent = percent + d.percent #here is problem, at least rails told me that 
  shares = shares + d.shares  
end %>

<% unless percent == 100 %>  
  Total percent needs to be 100%!
<% end %>

<% unless shares == @modification.entity.total_number %> 
  Not correct number!
<% end %>
```

Where is the problem? In database both `percent` and `shares` for boxes are integer.

Comment: Explain what those variables/methods are.

Comment: Share stack trace, at least few lines from top

Comment: @sawa `d.percent` and `d.shares` are percent and share count for each `box`. All are integers in DB. Local variables `percent` and `shares` are for counting everything together. Did I explain what you wanted?

Comment: How do you create `@modification` and how does the `boxes` method look?

Comment: @modification is database table. and each modification has many boxes. So they both are DB tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

You are declaring `percent` and `shares` as `percent = 0, shares = 0`. This will create percent as `Array` with value `[0,0]`.
Rather declare both as `percent = 0; shares = 0`. (notice the semicolon instead of comma)

```
2.1.5 :042 > percent = 0, shares = 0
 => [0, 0] 
2.1.5 :043 > percent
 => [0, 0] 
2.1.5 :044 > percent.class
 => Array
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment doesn't work as you expect:

```
percent = 0, shares = 0
```

because it is interpreted as:

```
percent = (0, (shares = 0))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
shares = 0
percent = 0, shares
```

The last line [implicitly creates an array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment). You could also write:

```
shares = 0
percent = [0, shares]
```

The "fix" is actually simple. You have to move the variables to the left-hand side and the values to the right-hand side:

```
percent, shares = 0, 0
```

This is called [multiple assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment).

---

BTW, instead of looping yourself, you could also use [`sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum):

```
percent = @modification.boxes.sum(&:percent)
shares  = @modification.boxes.sum(&:shares)
```